# Multiple HTML5 audio players with playlist. Will play the first playlist but a new window opens when playing the second list

Tags: jquery, html, html5-audio, playlist

I have two HTML5 audio players with a playlist on my site. More can be added depending on the user. The players not being used will be hidden and can be viewed if the user selects the player.

The problem I'm having is that the first player works fine but the second only plays the first track and nothing else and the first track is in new window.

Here's a demo of the problem - https://codepen.io/openbayou/pen/yLBvRaO

I think the best way to solve this is to assign the `init` to each player but this is beyond what I know and I don't know where to start.

```js
var audio;
var playlist;
var tracks;
var current;

init();

function init() {
  current = 0;
  audio = $('audio');
  playlist = $('#playlist');
  tracks = playlist.find('li a');
  len = tracks.length - 1;
  audio[0].volume = 1;
  
  playlist.find('a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    link = $(this);
    current = link.parent().index();
    run(link, audio[0]);
  });
  
  audio[0].addEventListener('ended', function(e) {
    if ($(audio).hasClass("repeat")) {
      current++;
      if (current > len) {
        current = 0;
        link = playlist.find('a')[0];
      } else {
        link = playlist.find('a')[current];
      }
      run($(link), audio[0]);
    } else if ($(audio).hasClass("repeat-trk")) {
      current++;
      if (current == len) {
        current = 0;
        link = playlist.find('a')[0];
      } else {
        link = playlist.find('a')[current];
      }
      run($(link), audio[0]);
    } else {
      current++;
      if (current < len) {
        current = 0;
        link = playlist.find('a')[0];
      } else {
        link = playlist.find('a')[current];
      }
      run($(link), audio[0]);
    }
  });
}

function run(link, player) {
  player.src = link.attr('href');
  par = link.parent();
  par.addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
  audio[0].load();
  audio[0].play();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<audio id="audio" preload="auto" tabindex="0" controls="" type="audio/mpeg">
  <source type="audio/mp3" src="http://www.archive.org/download/bolero_69/Bolero.mp3">
  Sorry, your browser does not support HTML5 audio.
</audio>
<ul id="playlist">
  <li class="active"><a href="http://www.archive.org/download/bolero_69/Bolero.mp3">Ravel Bolero</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://www.archive.org/download/MoonlightSonata_755/Beethoven-MoonlightSonata.mp3">Moonlight Sonata - Beethoven</a></li>
</ul>

<audio id="audio" preload="auto" tabindex="0" controls="" type="audio/mpeg">
    <source type="audio/mp3" src="https://ia801409.us.archive.org/3/items/soundA/soundA.mp3">
    Sorry, your browser does not support HTML5 audio.
</audio>
<ul id="playlist">
    <li class="active"><a href="https://ia801409.us.archive.org/3/items/soundA/soundA.mp3">Sound A</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://ia601404.us.archive.org/3/items/test_20190906/test.mp3">test</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You cannot use same element ID over and over again. That for audio and playlist elements... solve that and it will work.

Comment: I tried adding a class to the audio player and having the function look at that class, that didn't work. I added a class to the playlist, that didn't work as well. I don't know what else to do. `audio = $('.test'); playlist = $('.test');`